# blank page when loging in to backend part to magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I recently updated all of my features in Magento from 1.8 to 1.8.1 and after that I’m having problems to log in to the admin dashboard. If i go to “www.example.com/admin” i get a 500 Internal Server Error error and was googling around i wasn’t able to find a solution.

Then i noticed i can go to “www.example.com/index.php/admin” and then all it returns is a blank page. And after hosting the log in page locally sending the right information to the original hosting service i get logged in, but the dashboard is totally blank.

I’ve tried all of the mighty google advises I’ve found, for example, clearing catch, changing permission to folders, looking in log-files for solutions, changing in the .htaccess, etc. But still haven’t found out what the problem is. Anyone had the same problem and maybe has a solution or advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried enabling PHP error logging options? If so what errors are being recorded, otherwise do so and report back.

Comment: Yes, that did not work tho, it does not display any errors, sadly.

Comment: The number reason for this error I found was due to the folder permissions. It will not be sufficient enough to just set folder permissions to 777, it required me to command line and reset the folders using CHOWN. Is this one of the steps you've taking when looking at your folder permissions?

Comment: Yes and no, I've set the permissions but only with the GUI from the the ftp, maybe using the command line works better in some kind of weird way, I'll try that.